# no se genera mi cadena original CFDI 4.0 C#

Tags: c#

Buen día, estoy realizando un punto de venta con facturación del SAT (CFDI 4.0) pero al generar la cadena original solo me devuelve "|||", lo curioso es que tengo un código muy similar de ejemplo para facturación 3.3 y ahí no tengo problemas, podrían ayudarme.
De antemano les agradezco.

```
string pathCert = @"C:\Users\SISTEMAS\source\repos\cfdi40\certificado\30001000000400002335.cer";
SelloDigital.leerCER(pathCert, out aa, out b, out c, out noCertificado);

        Comprobante comprobante = new Comprobante()
        {
            Version = "4.0",
            Folio = txtFolio.Text,
            Fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
            NoCertificado = noCertificado,
            Certificado= "",
            Sello= "",
            SubTotal = dSubtotal,
            Moneda = "MXN",
            Total = dTotal,
            TipoDeComprobante = "I",
            MetodoPago = "PUE",
            Exportacion = "01",
            FormaPago = "99",
            LugarExpedicion = "72150"//codigo postal,
        };

        ComprobanteEmisor comprobanteEmisor = new ComprobanteEmisor()
        {
            Rfc = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            Nombre = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            RegimenFiscal = "605"
        };

        ComprobanteReceptor comprobanteReceptor = new ComprobanteReceptor()
        {
            Rfc = txtRFC.Text,
            Nombre = txtNombre.Text,
            DomicilioFiscalReceptor = txtCP.Text,
            RegimenFiscalReceptor = cbxRegimenF.SelectedValue.ToString(),
            UsoCFDI = cbxTipoG.SelectedValue.ToString()
        };

        List<ComprobanteConcepto> conceptos = new List<ComprobanteConcepto>();
        ComprobanteConcepto comprobanteConcepto = new ComprobanteConcepto()
        {
            Cantidad = 1,
            ClaveUnidad = "C62",
            Importe = dSubtotal,
            ClaveProdServ = "90101501",
            Descripcion = "CONSUMO EN GENERAL",
            ValorUnitario = dSubtotal,
            ObjetoImp = "02"
        };
        conceptos.Add(comprobanteConcepto);


        comprobante.Emisor = comprobanteEmisor;
        comprobante.Receptor = comprobanteReceptor;
        comprobante.Conceptos = conceptos.ToArray();

        GeneraXMl(comprobante);
```

con este código genero el xml sin problemas, el problema es con el siguiente código:

```
public string GeneradorCadenas()
    {
        string result;
        //Cargar el XML
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\SISTEMAS\source\repos\cfdi40\xml\cfdi.xml"); //comprobante
        XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(reader);

        //Cargando el XSLT
        XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
        myXslTrans.Load(@"C:\Users\SISTEMAS\source\repos\cfdi40\cfdi40\cadenaoriginal.xslt"); //xslt del SAT

        StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(str);

        //Aplicando transformacion
        myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);
        return result = str.ToString();
    }
```

Es en este ultimo donde retorna |||, eh visto en otras paginas que puede ser problemas en el xslt del SAT, pero no se como interpretarlo del todo para aventurarme a modificar eso

Comment: Te sugiero compartir el archivo de entrada o su contenido

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que el sat esta usando xslt 2.0 y tu estas usando transformacion 1.0 debes hacer una de dos cosas descargas una libreria como saxonia xslt 3.0 o algo asi o descargas los archivos xsl del sat y modificas la version de 2.0 a 1.0 y pones los includes a local en ves de a la pagina del sat. suerte con eso

Comment: Pudiste solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Tenia un caso similar al que comentas, al momento de emplear el código

```
string pathxsl = path + @"\cadenaoriginal_4_0.xslt";
System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform transformador = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform(true);
XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
transformador.Load(pathxsl);

using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
using (XmlWriter xwo = XmlWriter.Create(sw, transformador.OutputSettings))
{

  transformador.Transform(pathXML, xwo);
  cadenaOriginal = sw.ToString();
}
```

Me regresaba un string "|||" al final mi solución fue descargar los .xsd del SAT pero la versión **4.0**

Dichos xsd se convierten a clases y con eso ya permite la generación de la cadena original con el código que comentas, de igual forma si no quieres tener el **cadenaoriginal_4_0.xslt** puedes descargar la librería [sw-cadenaoriginal-netstandard](https://github.com/lunasoft/sw-cadenaoriginal-netstandard) tiene métodos para obtener directamente la cadena

En caso de que no quieras depender de internet existe un repositorio con las [utilidades](https://github.com/phpcfdi/resources-sat-xml/blob/master/resources/www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cadenaoriginal_4_0/cadenaoriginal_4_0.xslt) necesarias para generarlo con el codigo que tienes actualmente

Aquí lo importante es que tengas las clases en base a los .xsd de la versión 4.0